Strange oscillating sound at 2k rpm
I have a Hyundai i20 1.0TGDI with 80k kilometers
For the last 4 months there is a strange sound when RPMs reach around 2k and especially noticeable when RPMs are dropping (by going to neutral or letting go of the accelerator)
I have uploaded 2 mp3 files
https://whyp.it/tracks/211680/full-sound?token=mx9s9 (going at 2k rpm and letting off, at 16s keeping constant 2k rpm. Higher than that noise is drowned out)
https://whyp.it/tracks/211682/sound ( 2 seconds right on letting go of the accelerator)
Car was serviced some weeks before the issue started being noticeable. Do you have any ideas?

I have Hyundai i20 CVT and I also noticed some engine noise (more like grunting) at around 1500 RPM. At higher RPMs, no abnormal engine sounds observed. Not sure what could be the cause of this issue. Any ideas on source of this issue could be helpful.
